# Good examples of UI patterns for data assembling

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, nodes

I'm particularly interested in Node based UIs and I have a few questions:

**1.** What are good and elegant services in your opinion that use these pattern to create complex outputs? (I really like how https://lobe.ai/ manages to use this UI pattern in a very effective way).

**2.** Are there other alternative UI patterns that work well with data assembling like Nodes and Networks? (I'm thinking something like https://roli.com/products/blocks ).

**3.** Where can I find a list of UI patterns used in desktop software GUIs and services where the user has to assemble or build something. (Here I'm thinking to 3d softwares or Layer based UI of Photoshop).

Comment: Sorry, what is data assembling?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what a node based UI looks like... but based on the example of lobe.ai and roli.com (was this on Kickstarter?) I would say that:

1/ Software that allows users to create workflows has something similar to drag and drop of elements/objects and connecting them in some way.

- [XCode](https://www.macstories.net/mac/xcode-6-live-rendering-visual-view-debugging-and-swift/)
- [Adobe XD](https://theblog.adobe.com/introducing-adobe-experience-design-cc-preview/)

2/ Blocks works because there is a standard specification for how each module behaves and connects to other modules/blocks based on the size and layout patterns. The closest thing to this might be the Microsoft Fluent UI tiles (on a home page or dasboard) or typical dashboard designs that are more minimalistic like [Geckoboard](https://www.geckoboard.com/learn/dashboard-examples/marketing/aarrr-pirate-metrics-dashboard-example/) but correct me if this is not what you are talking about with UI patterns for data assembly (because I am not sure what that means).

3/ Software I can think off the top of my head used in building something

- [SketchUp](https://www.sketchup.com/)
- [SolidWorks](https://www.solidworks.com/)

But maybe you can also find it in places like http://ui-patterns.com/patterns or codepen.ioi?